# Is it possible to Pass values between C# and python and edit them both ways.

Tags: c#, python

I'm learning python for home automation a few months now and want to learn C# for building apps.

My python file is turning devices on and off automatically. Now I want to make an app that can read this python file, see if the device is on or off.( lamp=o or lamp=1 ). For this it must read a variable from python script.

Next I want to turn the device on or off on my mobile and with this action also change the variable in the script.

Is this all possible without making a text file for the status or using ironpython?

Read many stackoverflow questions about this, but all of them were using 1 device and most ironpython. If there is any good documentation about this subject I would be happy to receive it since I can't find one.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you expose an API endpoint and have your programs talk over the network? Your Python and C# apps can send/receive e.g. JSON.

Comment: No, you can't. A c# process can't access directly the memory used by a python one. You need to use some shared file or api to expose this data to c#

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way to do this would be to store the data in a shared resource of some kind.  Perhaps your python script could store values in a database and your C# application could refer to the database to retrieve the state of your bulbs, switches, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Any recommedation for a database software or file type? I Tried it with using simple text files but I got the feeling there is a faster way.